# Get back S3 response headers

Tags: 7

I have a video upload form which a) updates an entity table and the file_managed table in the Drupal database, and b) uploads the video file to Amazon S3 using the Drupal AmazonS3 module.

I also have a transcoder function which call AWS Elastic Transcoder to transcode the file in S3 into various formats.

Both functions currently work independently.

My problem is finding a way to trigger the transcoder function AFTER the file has successfully completed uploading to S3.

In a similar setup outside of Drupal, I have used the S3 response headers, success_action_redirect or success_action_status, to determine that the file has successfully uploaded, and then call another script.

Within Drupal, how can I trigger the transcode function after S3 reports a successful upload?  If using the S3 response headers is the way to go, how can I access those responses?